# How to substitute into general solution of ODE coefficients from Solve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a differential equation. After solving it, I look for the coefficients according to some boundary conditions that give a certain system of algebraic equations. How can I place back into the general solution the roots of the algebraic system?

```
k = DSolve[{y'''[z] == -I*Betta*y'[z] + B}, y[z], z];
roots = Solve[
0 == c1 + c2*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  c3/I*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(2*I*Betta) && 
0 == c1 + c2*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] - 
  c3/I*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] - B/(2*I*Betta) && 
1 == c2*I*(I*Betta)^0.5*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  c3*(I*Betta)^0.5*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(I*Betta) && 
1 == -c2*I*(I*Betta)^0.5*Sinh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + 
  c3*(I*Betta)^0.5*Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + B/(I*Betta), {c1, c2,
 c3, B}];
k2 = k /. {C[1] -> roots[[1, 1]], C[2] -> roots[[1, 2]], 
C[3] -> roots[[1, 3]], B -> roots[[1, 4]]}
```

At the end I would like to have a function which I can plot with standard methods

Comment: Why not directly express your equations in terms of the `C[k]`? `Solve[0 == C[1] +C[2] Cosh[I/2*(I*Betta)^0.5] + ... && (* equations *), {C[1], C[2], C[3], B}]`

Comment: @J.M. The equations (*equations*) are the ones that you also wrote in `Solve[0==C[1]+C[2] ...`. Maybe I wasn't clear, but I think your idea doesnt make sense. The first part of your Solve would be one of the equations that give the solution. The system of equations that give c1,c2,c3,B is exactly the one inside my Solve expressione. I want to substitute these solutions (which are given in vectorial form) INSIDE the function k(z) which comes from the DSolve and has got C[1],C[2],C[3],B.. inside, which I dont know how to replace with my c1,c2,c3,B.

Comment: The idea is that you don't need the extra effort to transfer, say, `c1`, into `C[1]`, since you can do `DSolve[(* stuff *)] /. Solve[(* stuff *)]`. That's why I'm saying that you can use `C[1]`, etc. instead of `c1`, etc. in `Solve[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Is there also a way to show each sine or cosine functions into sinh and cosh including imaginary unit. So far, I havent found much on documentation, rather the opposite.

Comment: @AndreaG What are the four conditions?

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal 
k(+-1/2)=0 and k'(+-1/2)=1. I have to look for c1,c2,c3,B. Two of the coefficients should be 0. As I said (where is my comment?just vanished) I am also having problems with the order Mathematica gives to the coefficients. The idea of J.M. worked well in terms of substitution, but then I realized I wasnt satisfying the boundary conditions when plottiong.

Comment: @MMM I'm sorry I missed your answer. I will check it as soon as possible and if satisfied I will vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = DSolve[{y'''[z] == -I*Betta*y'[z] + B}, y[z], z];
gsol[z_] = y[z] /. Flatten[k];
gdsol[z_] = D[y[z] /. Flatten[k], z];
findCs = Solve[{gsol[-1/2] == 0, gsol[1/2] == 0, gdsol[-1/2] == 1,
                gdsol[1/2] == 1}, {C[1], C[2], C[3], B}];
psol[z_, Betta_] = gsol[z] /. Flatten[findCs];
Plot[{Re[psol[z, 1]], Im[psol[z, 1]]}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MMM this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AndreaG I am pleased that it helped.